# Calling a soaplib method running on python in Java

Tags: java, python, soap, soaplib

I have the following situation, I have to use a web service written in python with the use of [soaplib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/soaplib/2.0.0-beta2) in Java. I can import the web service just fine in eclipse, but when I try to call a method of the web service I get the following error message ...

```
    AxisFault
     faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
     faultSubcode: 
     faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
     faultActor: 
     faultNode: 
     faultDetail:
```

So I tried to build my own little web service using soaplib to try this out. Here is the web service server running with soaplib and the internal http server. Simple method

```
    import soaplib
    from soaplib.core.service import rpc, DefinitionBase
    from soaplib.core.model.primitive import String, Integer
    from soaplib.core.server import wsgi
    from soaplib.core.model.clazz import Array
    from soaplib.core.service import soap

    class HelloWorldService(DefinitionBase):
        @soap(String,_returns=String)
        def say_hello(self,name):
            results = 'Hello, %s'%name
            print('Hello, %s' % name)
            return results

    if __name__=='__main__':
        try:
            from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
            soap_application = soaplib.core.Application([HelloWorldService], 'tns')
            wsgi_application = wsgi.Application(soap_application)
            server = make_server('pc-frank', 7789, wsgi_application)
            server.serve_forever()
        except ImportError:
            print "Error: example server code requires Python >= 2.5"
```

and this is the java class I try to use

```
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
    import static java.lang.System.out;
    import tns.*;

    public class testws {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            ApplicationProxy ws = new ApplicationProxy();
            try {
                String test   = ws.say_hello("world");
                out.println(test);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: I actually ended up using https://github.com/arskom/rpclib which works just great, so I recommend that to anyone trying to create a webservice with python.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either the request or the response is not parsing.  I would capture both and run them through a verification tool.  There are a lot of them around online that allow you to paste the XML in and see why it's not validating.